# JSP for adminstrating JBoss web service

Tags: web-services, jsp, servlets, jboss

For example, I write a simple code, pack it as *.jar and deploy WebService in JBoss, evrything works..

```
@WebService
@Stateless
public class TestService{
    static int takeMePlz = 1;
    @WebMethod
    public String GetAnsw(String str){
        ++takeMePlz;
        return Integer.toString(takeMePlz);
    }
}
```

So, when i call this web service, takeMePlz static varible increases.
My Serivce has location http://localhost:8080/test_service/TestService, 
Now i Want JSP with location: http://localhost:8080/test_service/Administrating,
that has access to my web service, and this JSP should show me takeMePlz static varible in web browser

Answer (score 1):

- Create client for webservice
- invoke webservice from servlet
- catch the result as attribute of request and forward it to jsp and on jsp use JSTL to show the data

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, i should create a servlet (separately of web service),
that has a webservice client, and this servlet calls web method of my web service to take
my variable. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you need to make the **takeMePlz** field public so it is accessible.
Moreover, you should synchronize access to the field, or make it a [java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

It will still be a bit rough though. Once you have it working, you might want to consider reimplementing using JMX.